# stuck, Need help returns time span from vector list

Tags: c++

I have a list of messages and every time I add a message I set a timestamp. I'm trying to create a function that will return the message that was added within a certain span of time that also matches a string. However, I'm now stuck, any help is much appreciated, below is my code:

```
struct BarMessage
{
    int Length;
    const char *message;
    time_t TimeAdded;
};

struct Ba
{
    vector<BarMessage> Messages;

    void AddMessage(const char *message, int Length)
    {
        BarMessage m;

        m.message = message;
        m.Length = Length;

        time(&m.TimeAdded); // set time ?

        Messages.push_back(m);
    }

    BarMessage & GetMessageWithin(string pattern, int span = 200)
    {
        //Time.Now?
        time_t now;
        time(&now);

        if (this->Messages.size() > 0)
        {
            for (auto & messages : this->Messages)
            {
                //Stuck here!!!

                //I want to return the BarMessage of a message
                //that was added within 200 (span)
                //that also contains the string patten inside it
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't need to check if there are items in your container, and if you do the right way to do it is `!Messages.empty()`

Comment: oh I don't know what you mean

Comment: Before doing anything else, start using std::string instead of char*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use string in BarMessage

```
struct BarMessage
{
    int Length;
    string message;
    time_t TimeAdded;
};
```

For more about finding matching string http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/ . Is there any good reason why you use `char*` instead of `string`? Are you sure you want to return a reference from this function?
Why do you pass pattern as a value not as a `const` referance ?

```
BarMessage & GetMessageWithin(const string& pattern, int span = 200)
{
    //Time.Now?
    time_t now;
    time(&now);

    if (this->Messages.size() > 0)
    {
        for (auto & messages : this->Messages)
        {
            if (now - messages.TimeAdded <= 200 && 
                messages.message.find(pattern) != std::string::npos) {
                //then return this message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I tried to use this but find was not defined, What exposes this method?

I tried <algorthim>

Comment: can you tell me what changes I need to do to make your example work?

Comment: you should you string in BarMessage as a message. Then you can call find on the message (as it is a string's member function).

Comment: As for your questions, I didn't know doing that was wrong.. so I shouldn't use & in the function?

Comment: pass pattern as const string& pattern, which is in general better.as you do not create a new copy of a string. But this is more about good programming style.